# What is the chemical formula(s) for liquid potassium-based soap?

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, soap

Many places say that liquid soap is generally potassium-based, while the solid stuff is sodium-based.

But, while I have found several sites saying that solid soap is usually sodium stearate, I can't find any place that gives a specific name(s) to the chemical(s) in liquid potassium soap...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to figure out? Why they use potassium or the exact formulas for the soap? Companies tend to use a range of surfactants depending on the application, i.e. food grade surfactants, industrial cleaners, etc. additionally, co-surfactants can be added to promote micelle formation.

Comment: The so called liquid soap is made of potassium stearate, mixed with some potassium palmitate. It is more efficient than sodium based soap.

Comment: Potassium salts of fatty acids are rather liquid, compared to sodium ones, but what is commonly sold under variations of liquid soap name, is not based on that. Personally I doubt I have ever met potassium liquid soap.

Answer (score 2):

You'll get an answer quickly if you search for "formulation liquid soap". There are for instance DIY guides on making liquid soap starting from natural oils (sunflower, coconut) by saponifying the oil with KOH. The fatty acid composition of sunflower oil can vary significantly depending on breed (see e.g. the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunflower_oil)) but generally contains mono- and polyunsaturated FAs in large proportion. Unsaturation contributes to the fluidity of the product. It is also worthwhile to check common nomenclature for FA chain length (e.g. see the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatty_acid)). Sunflower oil contains palmitic (C16:0) and stearic (C18:0) acids as principal saturated FAs. Coconut oil contains shorter (lauric, C12:0) and mainly saturated FAs. Mainly because of the extent of saturation, coconut oil has a higher melting point and is used as the minor component.

In addition there are plenty of commercial vendors willing to provide recipes you can follow to make your own liquid soap. Note not all require a potassium salt. For instance, the company Stepan provides a recipe which consists of mixing the following (in decreasing order of weight %) to form one phase (which is then mixed with another lacking detergents):

> Deionized Water
> BIO-TERGE® AS-40 (or BIO-TERGE® AS-40 HP)  ==  SODIUM C14-16 OLEFIN SULFONATE
> STEPANOL® AM  == AMMONIUM LAURYL SULFATE
> STEPANOL® WAT == TEA LAURYL SULFATE
> NINOL® M10  == COCAMIDE MIPA

Admittedly ammonium counterion (and TEA) is like potassium in that they are larger and softer counterions than sodium, so similar in their effect on the detergent.